# Navigation between pages is always preserving scroll (Not desired)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a standard **laravel + inertia + vue3** setup using **breeze**, and as Inertia docs says, navigation between pages should mimic browser default behavior reseting scroll to top when page loads. But it is not working this way in my case.

I don't have `preserveScroll: true` in my links but this happens anyway.

I have tried with a **vuejs** `onMounted()` hook to scroll to top when component loads, but immediately the page scrolls from top to last scroll position from previous page.
So I've deactivated this hook because its ugly flashing effect.

Any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My css file had a property `overscroll-behavior: contain;` applied to `body` tag. Since I removed it, everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to define the scroll region: https://inertiajs.com/scroll-management#scroll-regions

It seems that your app doesn't use document body scrolling.

Comment: Mhmm I'm using standard laravel markup for this ```<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    @inertia
</body>```. This generates an `app` div where vue app is injected. So I think you may be right, but I need to found now how to pass that parameter to inertia.

Comment: I can confirm that my html markup for inertia is exactly the same in pingcrm, so it leaves me even more confused

Answer (score 0):

**temporary** solution

in `Layout.vue`

```
    mounted(){
       Inertia.on('success', () =>
           window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'instant' })
       )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-bootstrap, you might try fixing this problem with the following code:

```
:root {
    scroll-behavior: inherit !important;
}
```

react-bootstrap sets scroll-behavior as 'smooth'. This was the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, but I'm using VueJS v3.

Comment: Good point. But, I would still look into the scroll-behavior property in the CSS. It affected the scroll behavior for me when it was set to smooth. Someone else on this thread had the same problem. Sorry about the react mistake.

Comment: In my case the solution was to remove `overscroll-behavior: contain` from my css file.