# Navigation between pages is always preserving scroll

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a standard Laravel, Inertia.js, Vue.js v3 setup with Vite, and as Inertia docs says, navigation between pages should mimic browser default behavior, reseting scroll to top when page loads. But it is not working this way in my case.

I don't have `preserveScroll: true` in my links but this happens anyway.

Comment: Are you using the inertia `Link` component for your page navigation?

Comment: @kjoedion yes :(

Comment: Maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/73168318

Comment: @ericmp doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it **temporarily** until someone give a solution ;')

in `Layout.vue`

```
    mounted(){
       Inertia.on('success', () =>
           window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'instant' })
       )
    }
```